# Calling and running other python files from a python file

Tags: python, call

so i checked several other links with similar titles but, It couldn't solve my specific question. I'm trying to run a python file in notepad++ which is not a problem to me however, this file takes in a few things in order for it to compile. This is how I successfully run it in the command prompt.

python upload.py --file= "video path" --title= "title" --description= "testing"

My question is, how would i set these attributes in a different python file and then just call that file instead?

here is my code that i have in my new file

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bthO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ8nG.png)

Comment: you can call the external module using subprocess.  More on that here:https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: @deweyredman i'm sorry but I've looked through it and couldn't see how this is beneficial. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sure, I'll create an answer to better explain what I'm talking about.

Comment: If you post the content of `upload.py` we can help you on how to call it from within a python script without using `subprocess`.

Comment: great ill do that.

Comment: i got it from youtubes api so here it is  https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/upload_video.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the subprocess module to do this.  Following the example from the docs and the code you've listed:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output('python upload.py --file="video path" --title="title" --description="testing"')
```

result will store any output from your command.

Note: if you're running in a windows environent, not linux, change the /usr/bin/python to python.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use subprocess to call your specific command.

In a separate file in the same folder, you can put a file like this:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("python upload.py --file= \"video path\" --title= \"title\" --description= \"testing\"")
```

And then you just call that file, and that's it...